# Sudden Upload HTTP errors, PHP uploads and memory limits are already to high to my taste. Anything else?

Tags: php, uploads, nginx, http

So, let me clear everything at the start:

- I'm not on shared hosting.
- PHP upload limit is already set for 700mb.
- PHP memory limit is set a 512mb.
- Nginx, PHP-FPM and WordPress' logs tells me *nothing* about uploads at the time of uploads.
- Restarting the server won't help.
- Core WordPress has seen no updates, and plugin stayed the same. Thing changed there.
- I do use a plugin to send files to S3, but deactivating it so the files stays on the local disk (which as plenty of space), I still get the HTTP error.

We've been uploading 100+mb files perfectly fine for ages. But this morning, trying to upload files that are more than ~5.5mb, I get the HTTP errors. If logs don't throw any errors, what is the else to do to debug those pesky HTTP error on file uploads?

Comment: You mention errors several times, but you never tell us what the errors are.  It would be a lot easier to help, if we knew what errors you are receiving, and if there is more going on than simply uploading files. Is there a specific file type? Or, is this for anything, including basic TXT text files?  Anything else you can tell us might be a big help in diagnosing this for you...

Comment: @MikeBaxter As far as _error_ go, I don't know more. The only thing that WordPress spew is "HTTP Error", in small font around the upload form. (And like I said, nothing comes out in server logs, so really, I don't know what _kind_ of errors). And as far as file types goes, it seems to be everything. I tried MP3, zips and images files (but did not want to create a 10mb txt files to test :P) Really, those are the only infos I could find myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [only article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-http-image-upload-error-in-wordpress/) I could find that seems to address such a generic issue.  They specifically talk about the generic "HTTP Error" message that you report.

Sorry!  I know it is very frustrating.

Hope they have the answer you need!

Comment: Sadly, they don't. Just the sake of keeping tabs on solutions, I'll adress them: error isn't temporary, it's be ongoing for the day; memory is set around 700mb, so this won't explain errors with 10 mb files; changing image library won't help because I get those errors with non-images files that won't go through GD or Imagemagick. I'll keep digging ! :(